# Best way to import large csv files from Azure Logic App to on premise database

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a Logic App that retrieves CSV files from a remote API and then sends the data that is contained in those files to an On Premise SQL Server via a Data Gateway.  Currently I am doing this by converting the .csv to an XML string and passing it to a stored procedure.  However, for larger files there is a default timeout of 120 seconds that appears to be non-configurable, so some of my imports are failing due to timeout.  I can think of two options to handle this, I'm not sure what is better.

1. Send the data in chunks (or at worst 1 record at a time).
2. Load the file somewhere the DB can read from and use BCP or similar.

Am I missing any other options? Both of these methods have some major drawbacks, so I'd like to hear some opinions on which would be better.

Comment: Exactly what has the 120 sec timeout?

Comment: why do you want to use logic apps for this and not data factory, for example?